# couldn't load "nokogiri" in the IRB

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have installed `nokogiri` in my required Ruby `lib` file as below:

```
C:\Ruby193>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

addressable (2.3.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.1.4)
bundler (1.2.3)
childprocess (0.3.6)
domain_name (0.5.7)
ffi (1.3.1 x86-mingw32)
git (1.2.5)
hoe (3.4.1)
httpclient (2.3.2)
io-console (0.3)
jar_wrapper (0.1.2)
jeweler (1.8.4)
json (1.5.4)
libwebsocket (0.1.7.1)
mechanize (2.5.1)
mechanize-downloader (0.0.1)
mime-types (1.19)
mini_magick (3.2.1)
minitest (2.5.1)
multi_json (1.5.0)
net-http-digest_auth (1.2.1)
net-http-persistent (2.8)
nokogiri (1.5.6 x86-mingw32)
ntlm-http (0.1.1)
progressbar (0.12.0)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rautomation (0.7.3)
rdoc (3.9.4)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
s4t-utils (1.0.4)
selenium (0.2.5)
selenium-webdriver (2.27.2)
subexec (0.0.4)
unf (0.0.5)
unf_ext (0.0.5 x86-mingw32)
user-choices (1.1.6.1)
watir-classic (3.4.0)
watir-webdriver (0.6.2)
webrobots (0.0.13)
websocket (1.0.6)
win32-api (1.4.8 x86-mingw32)
win32-process (0.7.1)
win32screenshot (1.0.7)
windows-api (0.4.2)
windows-pr (1.2.2)
xml-simple (1.1.2)
zip (2.0.2)
```

*Now In the below when I am trying  `nokogiri`,getting error as below,whereas it is installed in my desktop.*

```
C:\Ruby193>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'nokogiri'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0> require 'selenium-webdriver'
=> true
irb(main):003:0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to install the `mswin32-60` version instead of the `x86-mingw32` one?

```
gem install nokogiri --platform=x86-mswin32-60
```

**Edit**

Alternatively, try updating your rubygems version `gem update --system`

Comment: What is that `mswin32-60` ?

Comment: I am using `windows - xp 32` bit machine.

Comment: in `irb`, what is the output of `RbConfig::CONFIG["build"]`?

Comment: I tried as below : `irb(main):003:0> RbConfig::CONFIG["build"]
=> "i686-pc-mingw32"`

Comment: Ok, so your installed version of nokogiri should be fine, it is using the right platform at least. What does `gem --version` put out? if it is below 1.8.25, try upgrading using the edit from my answer. Also, does `gem contents nokogiri` show you that nokogiri is installed in the same folders as `rake`, for example?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you call `require 'rubygems'` before `require 'nokogiri'`